# Array values to string without foreach

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework, formatting

I am working on system with Zend Framework 1.12.
I have this array:

```
array (size=2)
0 => string 'Premia pieniężna 3 000,00 zł' (length=33)
1 => string 'test' (length=4)
```

Do you have any idea how to get array values as concatenated string?
I don't want to use foreach, because this array is generated using two foreach already.

(Desired result:

```
Premia pieniężna 3 000,00 zł
test
```

Comment: `implode('\n', $array);`

Comment: Great:) Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PHP implode function, like this:

```
$concat = implode("\n", $array);
```